# Reactjs unit test

Tags: reactjs

I have a LoginInfo component and under this component i am calling one more child component. I am trying to write unit test case for the components using jest,enzyme and react test utils. partially i have wrote the test cases but not sure how i can write test for child component (LoginInfoEdit). that line i am not able to cover.

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginInfoEdit } from './LoginInfoEdit'

 class LoginInfo extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isLoginInfo: false
    }
}
openEdit() {
    this.setState({ isLoginInfo: true })
}

closeEdit() {
    this.setState({ isLoginInfo: false })
}
OpenEditForUpdate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.openEdit();
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>                       
                <div>
                    some text
                </div>

                <LoginInfoEdit loginid={this.props.loginid} openloginedit={this.state.isLoginInfo} onClose={this.closeEdit.bind(this)}>                        
                </LoginInfoEdit>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}
 export default LoginInfo
```

Unit test is Below--------

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import LoginInfo from './LoginInfo'
 import LoginInfoEdit from './LoginInfoEdit'

const props = {
loginid: "1",
openloginedit: false,
};
describe('LoginInfo component', () => {
let LoginInfo = null;
let editButton = null;

beforeEach(() => {
    LoginInfo = shallow(<LoginInfo {...props}/>);
    editButton = LoginInfo.find('button[name="edit"]')
})

it('checks everything set properly', () => {
    editButton.simulate('click', { preventDefault: () => { } });
    expect(LoginInfo.state('isloginedit')).toEqual(true)
})
it('renders child', () => {
    expect(LoginInfo.find('LoginInfoEdit').length).toEqual(1)
});
it('passes proper props to the child', () => {
    const expected = {
    loginid: "1",
    openloginedit: false,
   onClose: LoginInfo.instance().closeEdit.bind(this),
 };

 expect(LoginInfo.find('LoginInfoEdit').props()).toEqual(expected)
}) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases I care only about checking whether we render the child and pass props we want to the child like:

```
let component;

const props = someProps;

beforeEach(() => { component = mount(<LoginInfo { ..props } />); });

it('renders child', () => {
  expect(component.find('LoginInfoEdit').length).to.eql(1)
});

it('passes proper props to the child', () => {
  const expected = {
    loginid: someVal,
    openloginedit: someotherVal,
    onClose: component.instance().closeEdit,
  };

  expect(component.find('LoginInfoEdit').props()).to.eql(expected)
});
```

and then I just test the children (in this case,  LoginInfoEdit) separately from the parent

Comment: Thanks for your answer but receive and expected is different in Expected i am getting - "onClose": [Function closeEdit], and in received i am getting -- "onClose": [Function onClose], so it is not matchniing. due to this test is failing

Comment: from the output it seems like you are passing different functions or different name of the function to the expected object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.From the output it seems but i am passing the same name like yo mentioned in the example..but after getting error i changed it to onClose: component.instance().closeEdit.bind(this). then i was getting "Difference:    Compared values have no visual difference." error. and test case is failing. not sure what is the problem.

Comment: can you post your test in the question, it will be easier for me to reaosn about this :) I assume the components you written here are the same ones you are using in you app right? I think, this is just mismatched functions in our expected object

Comment: I have updated the test in question. please have a look and suggest.

Comment: after adding `bind(this)` you binded the context of test case, that's why you get the no visual difference error. I'm pretty sure it's enough to do `onClose: component.instance().closeEdit` without binding anything. But now I've noticed you have not binded `closeEdit` in the constructor, could you add line `this.closeEdit = this.closeEdit.bind(this)` and remove the binding you are doing in the render method? (btw, binding in constructor is better for performance resons)